# Props undefined on access although console shows defined on class access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props

I'm taking a class where I have to build a website (I'm new to front end stuff!), but my professor and the TAs could not help me fix this problem (React Component, JavaScript).

- When I pass in a **variable as a prop** `<Stock ticker={stock.ticker}/>`, the variable is shown on the console as a
  prop, but when I try to access it, it becomes undefined.
- [Passing in **variable** as a prop: First output is
  `console.log(this);`, Second output is `console.log(this.props);` right after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iurpd.png)
- When I pass
  in a **String as a prop** `<Stock ticker="AMC"/>`, the string is
  shown on the console as a prop, and I am able to access it.
- [Passing in a **String** as a prop: First output is
  `console.log(this);`, Second output is `console.log(this.props);` right after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfNjS.png)

One observation is that in the **render()** function, props is **always defined**. At first I thought maybe it wasn't being mounted or some conditional render problem, but the fact that a String prop works might counter this? I have also tried using `<Stock ticker={String(stock.ticker)}/>` just in case a String wasn't passed, but the console already showed that the variable was a String prop.
Another weird observation is that when I update my code and save it during **npm start**, the variable as prop suddenly becomes defined. A refresh of the page makes it undefined again after this. Hard coded variables/downloaded json files also work completely fine.

Part of Component:

```
class Stock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // some stuff here
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStock();
  }

  getStock() {
    const key = secretstuff;
    let stock = this.props.ticker;
    console.log(this); // props says defined on console here
    console.log(this.props); // props is undefined on console here
    let call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${stock}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${key}`;
```

Parent Page:

```
    class Page extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            stock: {}
          }
        }
      
        componentDidMount() {
          this.getStock();
        }
      
        getStock() {
           const symbol = this.props.match.params.id; // this part works
           // some fetch code, works completely fine to show on page
        }
      
        render() {
            let stock = this.state.stock;
            return (
  <div>
      <h1>{stock.ticker}</h1> // WORKS
         <h2>{stock.name}</h2> // WORKS
             </div>
                <div>
                    <Stock ticker={stock.ticker}/> // DOESN'T WORK!
                           ...... etc ............
```

Comment: so where is your code?

Comment: Updated with part of the component mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'fetch code' that wasn't included likely works asynchronous.

This means your components will render at least twice, once before and once after the getStock completes.

Comment: ah ok thank you! i tried making it wait until it wasn't undefined and it works now

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the wrong `this`.
Add this inside your constructor to bind:

`this.getStock= this.getStock.bind(this);`

Comment: `class Stock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //stuff
    }
    this.getStock = this.getStock.bind(this);
  }`   Like this? It did not seem to work (still undefined props)

Comment: Ok. What is undefined (this or this.props)? Please add your parent code too in the ques.

Comment: "this" shows as defined on the console, also showing that a string is stored in its props. However, if you call "this.props" to show on the console, props suddenly shows as undefined. I added the parent code that uses this component.